# Read all Records on NTag213 using ACR1252U NFC Tag Reader

Tags: python, hex, nfc, acr1252, ntag21x

I am using an ACR1252U NFC Tag Reader to read NTag213 NFC Tags. I currently have a python program that successfully lets me connect and send commands to the reader & tag.

I am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve all of the records that are stored on the tag. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What type of "records", I assume you mean NDEF records not any other type of records?

Comment: @andrew, yes, and they are specifically text

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nfcpy` module to access the tag then the module module automatically reads any records on connect if the Tag has any NDEF data stored on it.

> An NFC Forum Tag can store NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF) Records in a specifically formatted memory region. NDEF data is found automatically and wrapped into an NDEF object accessible through the tag.ndef attribute. When NDEF data is not present the attribute is simply None

To read is then just:-

```python
assert tag.ndef is not None
for record in tag.ndef.records:
     print(record)
```

See https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html#read-and-write-tags for more details